# Environment configuration for Sinatra error

Tags: ruby, configuration, sinatra, config

I have an environment config file at  config/environment.rb with the following:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
```

and in my config.ru I have:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'slim'
require 'coffee-script'
require 'padrino-helpers'
require 'sinatra/twitter-bootstrap'
```

I am getting the error :

```
Errno::ENOENT at /profile
No such file or directory - /Users/myusername/projects/accounts/config/views/profile.slim
```

and this only goes away when I remove require 'sinatra' from the config/environment.rb file and into config.ru. Can anyone explain why this happens? I assumed that the  `require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)` will simply include all requires from that file into config.ru but that doesn't seem to be the case. It now thinks my views live inside the config folder.

I followed the suggestion given here: [How do I make Rake tasks run under my Sinantra app/environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692147/how-do-i-make-rake-tasks-run-under-my-sinantra-app-environment) but again, moving require 'sinatra' into the environment breaks the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error looks like it is from Sinatra being unable to find a Slim template when rendering a response, because it’s looking for a `views` directory under the `config` directory. By default Sinatra looks for the views dir relative to the application file, which (again by default) is the file that calls `require 'sinatra'`. In your case the require line is in `config/environment.rb` so Sinatra treats that as the app file and looks for the `views` dir below it.

I’m assuming you have an actual application file that you haven’t shown. The simplest solution is probably to [explicitly set the application file setting in there](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#appfile---main-application-file):

```
set :app_file, __FILE__
```

Depending on your setup you might want to [specify the view directory directly](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#views---view-template-directory) instead:

```
set :views, 'path/to/views'
```

Comment: Setting the views properly did the trick. My application exists inside my config.ru so that method is best suited for my purposes. Thank you so much!