# Cant load models folder in my rake task for Sinatra project

Tags: rake-task, sinatra-activerecord

I have a simple rake task that requires some models. 
I cant require model in my rake task.
I have tried following.

```
Dir.glob("../../models/*.rb").each { |r| require_relative r }
```

My rake task in it lib/tasks
when i do rake -T i can see my task. But when i try to run i get

> uninitialized constant [ClassName]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Used require_relative and all was fixed. Plus following question has great answer to this problem.
You can load your whole environment in a rake task.

[How do I make Rake tasks run under my Sinantra app/environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692147/how-do-i-make-rake-tasks-run-under-my-sinantra-app-environment)